Does moderating a conference panel go on a CV?
Should moderating conference panels go on an academic CV and, if so, where? I am in a humanities-related field, if that matters.
Thank you!

Yes, no, maybe? Sure, it shows some level of engagement with the field. But if you are being invited to do that, there is probably a good reason that warrants more attention in your CV?

It's one extra line in your community service section. No less, no more.

It shows some scientific engagements. But how is it provable (verifiable)? Most conferences (the ones I have experience) don't give any certificate for moderating conference panels.

Thee sorts of questions Jon and m123 are asking are why I have been unsure. I noticed "The Professor is In" spoke about this briefly in the Q/A part of this blog post on CVs (https://theprofessorisin.com/2016/08/19/dr-karens-rules-of-the-academic-cv/?unapproved=1832264&moderation-hash=c7447fd523fe1b798ac99343de93a967#comment-1832264), which made me curious. I would also add that many conferences in my field (theology) aren't formally verifiable with certificates, you just keep your documentation/event schedules if you feel the need.

@m123 The conferences I attend put their schedules online, including things like who is chairing which session. They keep them up long after the conference has ended, so in my field at least, it would be verifiable. As Captain Emacs says, though, it’s only a community service line on a CV, so not something anyone is likely to bother to fake or check.

@Significance: So the conference' website is enough if they need to check. Thanks.

@m123 I've never got a certificate from a conference for anything, do you?

@AzorAhai-him- :Yes, some conferences give certificate for reviewing the papers. Also, they sometimes give certificate to the managers/chief of committees (scientific,...)

Everything can go on a CV, and when you're early in your career, everything probably should go on your CV. As you have more and more stuff on your CV as you move along in a career, you remove the things that don't seem that important any more, and moderating a panel may get the ax. But that's for a later time.

Maintain a master copy of your CV that has everything on it, and then cut this down as needed for individual job applications etc. Sometimes (e.g. for grant applications or promotion cases) having a proper record of your more esoteric activities can be really useful.

Make a complete cv for yourself and put it on, that way you have the information available. When providing a cv make a focussed cv based on why you need it. That allows you on a case by case basis to use it or not
